# getting proper key setup for both version control and deployment

Tags: git, openssl, capistrano

Struggling with OpenSSL 3 and deployment from M1 with 12.3 to Ubuntu 22.04

The application was not deploying because of

```
Net::SSH::Authentication::KeyManagerError: the given identity is known, but the private key could not be loaded: 
OpenSSL::PKey::PKeyError (rsa#set_key= is incompatible with OpenSSL 3.0)
```

Local homebrew on M1 with 12.3 installed only had Openssl1.1 in `opt/homebrew/Cellar`; thus `brew install openssl@3`.  And we have a potential banana peel with two versions set up locally.

That still generated the same error as above.

A [number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/638043/how-to-convert-rfc4716-private-keys-to-pem-private-keys) of [sources](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/issues/874#issuecomment-1442459666) indicate that to work properly the private key has to be converted to PEM format:

Attempt `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "valid@mail.com" -m PEM` allows a successful `ssh -T git@github.com`. Copying the key over `ssh-copy-id deploy@server_ip`  allows to ssh into the server.

But now when deploying from the M1 to Ubuntu via `cap development deploy`

```
00:00 git:check
      01 git ls-remote git@github.com:deploy/app_name.git HEAD
00:00 git:check
      01 git ls-remote git@github.com:deploy/app_name.git HEAD
      01 git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
      01 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
      01
      01 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
      01 and the repository exists.

.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.4/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as deploy@server_ip: git exit status: 128 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

github is denying access to the repository.

*out of completeness, the following appears to process correctly*

```
git ls-remote git@github.com:deploy/app_name.git
c317346688eeb92d992a0a98db89719c83a574bd    HEAD
c317346688eeb92d992a0a98db89719c83a574bd    refs/heads/main
```

There is a major grey area here that is utterly confusing; there is no obvious problem candidate. How can this deployment occur properly?

Comment: There seems to be two systems involved in the question: 1) your M1 Mac, 2) some Ubuntu server. In which system is GitHub denying access? Your Mac or the Ubuntu server? Is this `cap` command executing commands on your Mac or on the Ubuntu server?

Comment: Edited the question.  from M1 to Ubuntu server